# Join objects with one same property within different arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this array, that contains more arrays with objects inside that contains information about words founded in pages. Here one example:

```
let data = [
  [],
  [{
      "word": "society",
      "count": 5,
      "pageIndex": 1
    },
    {
      "word": "identity",
      "count": 2,
      "pageIndex": 1
    }
  ],
  [{
      "word": "society",
      "count": 2,
      "pageIndex": 2
    },
    {
      "word": "identity",
      "count": 2,
      "pageIndex": 2
    }
  ],
  [{
      "word": "society",
      "count": 2,
      "pageIndex": 3
    },
    {
      "word": "identity",
      "count": 1,
      "pageIndex": 3
    }
  ],
  [],
  [],
  [{
    "word": "society",
    "count": 1,
    "pageIndex": 6
  }],
  [],
  [{
    "word": "society",
    "count": 1,
    "pageIndex": 8
  }],
  [{
    "word": "society",
    "count": 1,
    "pageIndex": 9
  }]
]
```

What I want is to build a final array of objects with this structure to join the information of each word founded in just one object

```
const final = [{
    "word": "society",
    "countFinal": 12,
    "pagesIndexes": [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]
  },
  {
    "word": "identity",
    "countFinal": 5,
    "pagesIndexes": [1, 2, 3]
  }
]
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this in JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will first flat the data, afterward you can `reduce` (in order to group data based on `word` property). Once reduced, you can take `Object.values` of the object. Here is an implementation:

```js
var data = [ [], [{ "word": "society", "count": 5, "pageIndex": 1 }, { "word": "identity", "count": 2, "pageIndex": 1 } ], [{ "word": "society", "count": 2, "pageIndex": 2 }, { "word": "identity", "count": 2, "pageIndex": 2 } ], [{ "word": "society", "count": 2, "pageIndex": 3 }, { "word": "identity", "count": 1, "pageIndex": 3 } ], [], [], [{ "word": "society", "count": 1, "pageIndex": 6 }], [], [{ "word": "society", "count": 1, "pageIndex": 8 }], [{ "word": "society", "count": 1, "pageIndex": 9 }]];

var result = Object.values(data.flat().reduce((a,{word, count, pageIndex})=>{
    a[word] = a[word] || {word, countFinal:0, pageIndexes:[]};
    a[word].countFinal+=count;
    a[word].pageIndexes.push(pageIndex);
    return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: wow, this is amazing. One question,is it possible to use flat already in node and in all browsers?

Comment: @Rusty23 yes, if you can include support of `es2016` inside your angular project then it is possible.

Comment: @Rusty23 or if you have any third party library such as `lodash` or `ramda` then you have `flatten` or `flat` method to flat the array data.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [
  [],
  [{
    "word": "society",
    "count": 5,
    "pageIndex": 1
  }, {
    "word": "identity",
    "count": 2,
    "pageIndex": 1
  }],
  [{
    "word": "society",
    "count": 2,
    "pageIndex": 2
  }, {
    "word": "identity",
    "count": 2,
    "pageIndex": 2
  }],
  [{
    "word": "society",
    "count": 2,
    "pageIndex": 3
  }, {
    "word": "identity",
    "count": 1,
    "pageIndex": 3
  }],
  [],
  [],
  [{
    "word": "society",
    "count": 1,
    "pageIndex": 6
  }],
  [],
  [{
    "word": "society",
    "count": 1,
    "pageIndex": 8
  }],
  [{
    "word": "society",
    "count": 1,
    "pageIndex": 9
  }]
];

let end_obj = {}
data.forEach(element => {
  element.forEach(sub => {
    if (!end_obj[sub.word]) {
      end_obj[sub.word] = {
        word: sub.word,
        countFinal: 0,
        pagesIndexes: []
      }
    }
    end_obj[sub.word].countFinal += sub.count
    end_obj[sub.word].pagesIndexes.push(sub.pageIndex)
  });
});

let end_arr = []
for (const key in end_obj) {
  const element = end_obj[key];
  end_arr.push(element)
}

console.log(end_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). The map would store keys which are the words from each object, along with its values being the modified objects with arrays for the `pagesIndexes` value. Whenever you come across a word that is already a key in the map, you can add to its `pagesIndexes` array. If you encounter a new word that isn't in the map, you can start a new array of its associated object which contains the current objects `pageIndex`. You can then grab the values from your Map using `.values()` and [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the value iterator into an array.

See example below

```js
const data = [[], [{ "word": "society", "count": 5, "pageIndex": 1 }, { "word": "identity", "count": 2, "pageIndex": 1 } ], [{ "word": "society", "count": 2, "pageIndex": 2 }, { "word": "identity", "count": 2, "pageIndex": 2 } ], [{ "word": "society", "count": 2, "pageIndex": 3 }, { "word": "identity", "count": 1, "pageIndex": 3 } ], [], [], [{ "word": "society", "count": 1, "pageIndex": 6 }], [], [{ "word": "society", "count": 1, "pageIndex": 8}], [{ "word": "society", "count": 1, "pageIndex": 9 }] ];

const res = Array.from(data.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  return new Map([...acc, ...arr.map(c => {
    const o = acc.get(c.word);
    return [c.word, {...o, ...c, pagesIndexes: [...(o && o.pagesIndexes || []), c.pageIndex]}];
  })]);
}, new Map).values());

console.log(res);
```